# Why is Google Chrome not opening, though I have installed it using apt-get -f install?

Tags: kali-linux, chrome

I am using Kali Linux and I have successfully installed Google Chrome, but I am unable to open it.
I installed Chrome using `apt-get -f install` as the `dpkg` command was not working for me. It shows error. After installation using `apt-get -f install` the commands runs fine without any error, but where is the Chrome browser? I can't open it.

Comment: Kali is not intended as a desktop distro. It's a distro designed around a set of tools for a very specific usage and geared towards professional and highly skilled Linux users. The way you posted suggests you are not part of Kali's target audience. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me . Install and use ANY other proper desktop Linux distro, download and install the deb or rpm file for Google Chrome. Done!

Answer (score 1):

Try inputting to your Terminal `google-chrome-stable`

Alternatively, you might have google-chrome-unstable or google-chrome-beta.

To find an executable we use the command which, as in `which google-chrome-stable`

To find every occurrence of a program we use the command whereis, as in `whereis google-chrome-stable`